# How can I regain permissions to my desktop? Mac

Tags: macos

I own a 2018 MacBook Air and I am the administrator of my computer. But for some reason, my mac thinks that I do not have permission for my desktop. I am running macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta but I don't think that's what the problem is. It all started when an apple technician ran code in my terminal.

Comment: This is probably not the right plattform to discuss this problem related to macOS.

Comment: Upgrade away from beta, otherwise you should use the official Apple dev forum.